# Errors in my Tic-Tac-Toe Game

Tags: c

Here's my code for my tic-tac-toe game:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int board[3][3] = {
                        {0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0}
                  };

int main (void)
{
    int const user1 = 1;
    int const user2 = 2;
    char move[10];

    while (! all_locations_filled()) {
        printf("User-1, please enter your move:");
        scanf("%s", move);

        if(valid_location(move)) {
            mark_location(user1, move);
            display_board(board[3][3]);
        }
        else if(won_the_game(user1)) {
            printf("Congratulations User-1, You Won the Game!");
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Invalid Move");
        }

        printf("User-2, please enter your move:");
        scanf("%s", move);

        if(valid_location(move)) {
            mark_location(user2, move);
            display_board();
        }
        else if(won_the_game(user2) {
            printf("Congratulations User-2, You Won the Game!");
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Invalid Move");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

bool valid_location(char str[10]) {
    int strcmp(x, y);

    if (strcmp(str[10], "upperLeft") == 0 || strcmp(str[10], "up") == 0 || strcmp(str[10], "upperRight") == 0 || strcmp(str[10], "left") == 0 || strcmp(str[10], "center") == 0 || strcmp(str[10], "right") == 0 || strcmp(str[10], "lowerLeft") == 0 || strcmp(str[10], "down") == 0 || strcmp(str[10], "lowerRight") == 0)
        return true;
}

void mark_location(int userU, char str[10]) {
    int strcmp(x, y);

    if (strcmp(str[10], "upperLeft") == 0)
        board[0][0] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str[10], "up") == 0)
        board[0][1] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str[10], "upperRight") == 0)
        board[0][2] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str[10], "left") == 0)
        board[1][0] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str[10], "center") == 0)
        board[1][1] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str[10], "right") == 0)
        board[1][2] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str[10], "lowerLeft") == 0)
        board[2][0] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str[10], "down") == 0)
        board[2][1] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str[10], "lowerRight") == 0)
        board [2][2] = userU;
}

char display_board(int array[][]) {
    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<3; ++i)
        for (j=0; j<3; ++j)
            if (array[i][j] == 0)
                print("-");
            else if (array[i][j] == 1)
                print("x");
            else if (array[i][j] == 2)
                print("o");
}

bool all_locations_filled() {
    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<3; ++i)
        for (j=0; j<3; ++j)
            if board[i][j] == 0
                return false;
    return true;
}

bool won_the_game(userU) {
    int i, j;

    if (board[0][0] == userU && board[0][1] == userU && board[0][2] == userU)
        return true;
    else if (board[1][0] == userU && board[1][1] == userU && board[1][2] == userU)
        return true;
    else if (board[2][0] == userU && board[2][1] == userU && board[2][2] == userU)
        return true;
    else if (board[0][0] == userU && board[1][0] == userU && board[2][0] == userU)
        return true;
    else if (board[0][1] == userU && board[1][1] == userU && board[2][1] == userU)
        return true;
    else if (board[0][2] == userU && board[1][2] == userU && board[2][2] == userU)
        return true;
    else if (board[0][0] == userU && board[1][1] == userU && board[2][2] == userU)
        return true;
    else if (board[2][2] == userU && board[1][1] == userU && board[2][0] == userU)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

There are a few errors that I don't understand, here they are:

```
tictactoe.c:50: error: expected expression before ‘}’ token
```

This error is at the end of the main function but I'm not sure what I did wrong.

```
tictactoe.c:52: error: nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable
```

I didn't know I used a nested function.

```
tictactoe.c:53: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
```

This is referring to int strcmp(x, y)

```
tictactoe.c:55: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

What did I do wrong with strcmp?

If someone could help me out I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: As well as other problems identified, you have `bool valid_location(char str[10]) {
    int strcmp(x, y);
`  I assume that's an attempt to declare `strcmp()`; you don't need to do it because you included `<string.h>` and you can't do it like that even if you want to do it (because `x` and `y` aren't types, for the sordid details of why; you'd want to write `int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);` if you really wanted to declare the function).

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing parenthesis here (line #40):

```
else if(won_the_game(user2) {
```

Should be:

```
else if(won_the_game(user2)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple or problems with the `strcmp` as well.

```
strcmp(str[10], "upperRight")
```

The compiler is complaining about the first parameter `str[10]`. One problem is that this selects a single character from the string, and not the whole string. Another problem is that in an array of size 10, the positions are numbered 0..9 so there isn't even a position 10!

Also, a string literal like `"upperRight"` contains 10 visible characters *plus* an extra zero character as a terminator. So it needs 11 positions when stored in the `str`.

Comment: How do I make strcmp recognize the whole string and not just a character?

Comment: By passing the whole string :-) Use `strcmp(str, "some value")` but make sure the `str` array is large enough to hold the string value.

Comment: I'm getting the same error message. Still says passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast. What exactly does that mean?

Comment: I mean you explained that but why am I getting the same error message?

Comment: In C a `char` is treated like a small integer. Its value is the (ASCII) code for the character it contains. In the call to `strcmp` both parameters need to be pointers, and not integers. That is what the compiler tries to tell you. There are many calls in the code you posted - have you fixed all of them?

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't aware that the parameters needed to be pointers.

Comment: Still getting the same error message after I turned the two parameters into pointers.